# How can I put the second array in the end of merged array?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Here is my code:

```
$arr1 = ['p' => 2, 'pm' => 1];
$arr2 = ['p' => ''];
print_r(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));
```

And [here](https://3v4l.org/OjLAI) is the current output:

```
Array
(
    [p] => 
    [pm] => 1
)
```

And here the expected result:

```
Array
(
    [pm] => 1
    [p] => 
)
```

Because the send array (`$arr2`) in `array_merge()` contains `p` key, so I want to put it in the end. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but I would remove the entries first and then add them again:

```
print_r(array_merge(array_diff_key($arr1, $arr2), $arr2));
```

Docs for [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php).